# Calling solidity functions to reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity

I'm new to ReactJS & Solidity. I'm testing the web interface of a solidity smart contract.

The main goal of the smart contract is to take to add files (description+hash) and request the number of files.

When I test it with remix it works very well, so the problem is in the connexion between Solidity and React.

Any help?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';
import { Form, Button, Input, Message } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import auction from '../../src/auction';
import web3 from '../../src/web3';

class FileNew extends Component {
  state = {
    description: '',
    hash: '',
    fileCounts: ''
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const manager = await auction.methods.manager().call();
    const fileCounts = await auction.methods.FileCounts().call();
    this.setState({ manager, fileCounts });
  }

  onSubmit = async (event) => {
    await auction.methods.addFile(this.setState.description, this.setState.hash);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
     <h1> Create new file </h1>
      <Form >
          <Form.Field>
            <label>desc</label>
            <Input label="First Name" labelPosition="right" value={this.state.description}
             onChange={event =>
               this.setState ({description: event.target.value})}
             />
             <label>hash</label>
             <Input label="Last Name" labelPosition="right" value={this.state.hash}
              onChange={event =>
                this.setState ({hash: event.target.value})}
              />
              <Button type='submit' onClick={this.onSubmit}>Submit</Button>

          </Form.Field>
          <p>The number of files is {this.state.fileCounts}</p>
        </Form>
     </Layout>
    );
  }
}
export default FileNew
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onSubmit` method of `FileNew` component, properties of its state are accessed the wrong way from `this.setState`.

Use ...

```
onSubmit = async (event) => {
  try {
     await auction.methods.addFile(this.state.description, this.state.hash);
  } catch (e) {
     // Send error to Error reporting service in 
     // production/staging stage or log to console in dev.
     console.error(e);
  }

}
```

Comment: No working ! the number of files is not incrementing

Comment: Is it possible for `auction.methods.addFile` to raise an `Error`?

Comment: I made some changes and i think now the connection is established successufully but with some errors. i changed onSubmit to look like this onSubmit = async (event) => {
    const accounts = web3.eth.getAccounts();
    await auction.methods.addFile({
      description: this.state.description,
      hash: this.state.hash
    });
  }; 
and now i get this error from the console : Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid number of parameters for "addFile". Got 1 expected 2!

Comment: Can you share the method signature for `auction.methods.addFile`? Also you want to wrap that in a try/catch. I've edited the sample to show that.

Comment: function addFile(string _description, string _hash) public  {
        FileCounts++;
        files[FileId] = file(_description, _hash);
        FileId++;
        emit _fileCreated(FileId);
    }

Comment: Your previous comment shows you passing an object to the `addFile` method. The signature is expecting positional arguments like I have passed it in my answer.